# Java Classpath is incomplete, getting error in visual studio code for new java class

Tags: visual-studio-code, java-8

I am creating java class for first time in visual studio code and getting error Java classpath incomplete. My java class below is in src folder:

```
public class PreviligedCustomer extends Customer {
  
    public double chargeOnDelivery()
    {
return 0;
    };
    public  double discount()
    {
        System.out.println("Hello");
        return 5;
    }
    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the simplest way to make this work in visual studio code is to right click on src folder and add it to java source path.

This way, we can make it work without adding any new configurations like maven or switching to other IDE's like eclipse, NetBeans etc.

After error is gone, simple right click on java source file and run it or click F5.